# Visual Basic: changing the value of a variable depending on second condition

Tags: vb.net

I have a variable called test. Its value is random (from 1 to 6). It decides which question to ask the user from a list of 6 questions. The user can also choose which questions they'd like to be asked by checking their check boxes. I would like to write a function that changes the value of test if the user hasn't checked the corresponding box and doesn't want to be asked that question.

I wrote the function below, the first time without the return. I added the return later but it doesn't work either way. Not sure if it should be there.

```
Private Function testchange(ByRef test As Integer)
    okay = False
    While okay = False
        okay = True
        If test = 1 And PageOptions.cb1checked = False Then
            test = 2
            okay = False
        End If
        If test = 2 And PageOptions.cb2checked = False Then
            test = 3
            okay = False
        End If
        If test = 3 And PageOptions.cb3checked = False Then
            test = 4
            okay = False
        End If
        If test = 4 And PageOptions.cb4checked = False Then
            test = 5
            okay = False
        End If
        If test = 5 And PageOptions.cb5checked = False Then
            test = 6
            okay = False
        End If
        If test = 6 And PageOptions.cb6checked = False Then
            test = 1
            okay = False
        End If
    End While
    Return test
End Function
```

When I set test to 1 and only check checkbox3, the value of test at the end should be 3 but is 2.

Comment: Look at your code again. Your first 'If' statement  applies, and sets test to 2.

Comment: Instead of using "And" use "AndAlso"

Comment: @peterG doesn't the second if statement set it to 3? Since all of the cbchecked are false except cb3checked.

Comment: @Mr.Tripodi didn't work :(

Comment: You have *When I set test to 1 and only check checkbox3*. So, `PageOptions.cb3checked = True`. Since the first condition is: `Test = 1 AND True` because `PageOptions.cb1checked` is NOT checked, so `Checked = False` is `True`. Which gives you `True AND True`.

Comment: If none of those "cbXchecked" variables are true, it will get stuck in an infinite loop...

Comment: @Jimi yeah, so test gets the value 2. Then, in the second if statement there's True and True again which sets test to 3. The ifs after that are all false so test should be 3 at the end. At least that's how I see it.

Comment: If `test = 1`, the second condition is not met: `test = 2 => False`.

Comment: @Jimi But doesn't test become 2 in the first if statement?

Comment: I was too hasty. YOur code is more convoluted than I thought at first sight! As shown I think it executes the while loop twice but returns 3

Comment: I put AndAlso in the if statements as @Mr.Tripodi suggested and changed some other things in another function and it works! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Yes, maybe what I wrote wasn't understandable. I'm just referring to the first condition and the AND comparison. If the second part of the third condition is set to `False`, because `PageOptions.cb3checked = False` is `False`, then the loop will repeat and you will exit with `test = 3`. If all the second parts of all conditions are `True`, the loop is infinite. Anyway, with the given parameters `test = 1` and all `PageOptions.cb3checked = False` = `True`. it will return `test = 3`.

Comment: Don't use `ByRef` is you want reliable results. The function is `Private Function testchange(ByVal test As Integer) As Integer`. Use a local variable, assign it the value of `test` and return that variable. Otherwise, your `test` may change anywhere in between the calls.

Comment: Like @Jimi mentioned, change the `test` input param to ByVal.  It's not all that common to pass values into a function ByRef.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those are shared variables in PageOptions, you could do something like this:

```
Private Function testchange(ByRef test As Integer)
    Static po As New PageOptions
    For i As Integer = 1 To 6
        If CallByName(po, "cb" & test & "checked", CallType.Get) Then
            Return test
        Else
            test = test + 1
            If test = 7 Then
                test = 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return -1 ' nothing was checked
End Function
```

This will find the next available number, in order - with wrap around, that was checked, or -1 if no boxes were checked.